# Does Cortana have age restrictions?

Tags: cortana

Does Windows Phone Cortana Have Any Sort Of Age Restrictions? I have tried to use Cortana but it says you must be older in order for me to help you.

Answer (score 8):

This depends on your country of residence and whether or not there are any laws in that country that limit children's ability to use online services.

In the US, you need to be at least **13 years old** (as determined by your date of birth in your [Microsoft account](https://account.live.com/summarypage.aspx) details) in order to be able to use Cortana. The reason for this limit is the [Children's Online Privacy Protection Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act) (COPPA).

Sources: [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpupdate/age-minimum-to-use-cortana/5bba021c-a3e2-4920-afb8-e5a75dbd3dd3?msgid=c399d900-f92f-4fb0-aa81-be1abdcfb28a), [WPCentral](http://www.wpcentral.com/sorry-kids-you-must-be-thirteen-or-older-use-cortana)

In other countries and regions, Cortana's availability will probably also be subject to any similar laws. Expect information regarding this to become available if and when Cortana is released outside the US.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. A lot of online services in the US restricts use to people above the age of 13, mandated by the [Children's online privacy protection act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act). Surprisingly though I haven't been able to find a reference for a similar restriction with Apple Siri.